# Change hyperlink text using jquery in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code to change hyperlink text in jquery :

```
$('#exampleDropdown li a').click(function () {
    $("#hyperlink").text($(this).text());
}
```

This works in all browsers, but not in IE9. When I gave console.log,

```
console.log($(this).text());
```

is logging proper values, but the `$("#hyperlink").text($(this).text());`
is not working. So I presume that changing value through .text() method does not work in IE9. Please give me an alternate method to achieve this.

Comment: Add `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler.

Comment: I tried both. I think that's not the solution. It does not solve my problem, neither does it propagate the click. I want an alternate method for text, which can do the trick in IE9.

Comment: It doesn't matter with event propagation I guess.. It has to do with the text() method not able to update the new value while using IE9.
It happens before event is propagated right..

Comment: Sometimes Console.log gives error in IE browsers. Try to remove console logs and check.

Comment: No. I just used console.log() for debugging.

Comment: Anyway, I fixed my problem with <span> instead of <a>, but there was no valid alternative